# I need users to proceed to the next page on mouseover in javascript with turn.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover

I'm having a problem with the turn.js api.

Rather than using this for a book, I'm trying to use it for an ad I'm developing. Basically, I want to have the first page immediately 'uncover' the second page when the user hovers over the page, but can pull from the corner on page 2 (as normal) to go back to the first.

I'm thinking that I could set a function of **onmouseover** to **mousedown** or something like that. Or maybe something totally different.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Nothing that has worked. The API's documentation isn't very clear and I don't use JS very frequently. 

Here's what I tried:

`
$('.flipbook').turn({
                when: {
                    first: function(event) {
                        event.onmouseover(mousedown);
                    }
                }
            });
`

Comment: sorry, i can't get code to display right on here.